# How to interpret ASCII codes returned by "ga" command?

Tags: microsoft-windows, unicode, encoding

I'm cleaning data imported from Excel to Access, and ran across funny quotes that I'm having trouble getting unambiguous ASCII codes for.

They are the hooked single quotes `‘` and `’`.  Vim's `ga` command show them to have decimal codes `8216` and `8217`, but Microsoft's ASC function shows them to have decimal codes `145` and `146`.  In the end, I used Microsoft's `CHR(145)` and `CHR(146)` to locate and clean them, but I was wondering how to interpret the larger numbers returned by Vim.

The Microsoft numbers do not have bit patterns that are subsets of the larger Microsoft numbers:

```
octave:6> dec2bin([145 146])

   10010001
   10010010

octave:5> dec2bin([8216 8217])

   10000000011000
   10000000011001
```

My vim version details are below.

Thanks.

Vim version details:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May 20 2015 22:20:54)
Included patches: 1-729
Compiled by <cygwin-xfree@cygwin.com>
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -ebcdic          +localmap        +printer         +title
+arabic          +emacs_tags      +lua/dyn         +profile         +toolbar
+autocmd         +eval            +menu            +python/dyn      +user_commands
+balloon_eval    +ex_extra        +mksession       +python3/dyn     +vertsplit
+browse          +extra_search    +modify_fname    +quickfix        +virtualedit
++builtin_terms  +farsi           +mouse           +reltime         +visual
+byte_offset     +file_in_path    +mouseshape      +rightleft       +visualextra
+cindent         +find_in_path    +mouse_dec       +ruby/dyn        +viminfo
+clientserver    +float           -mouse_gpm       +scrollbind      +vreplace
+clipboard       +folding         -mouse_jsbterm   +signs           +wildignore
+cmdline_compl   -footer          +mouse_netterm   +smartindent     +wildmenu
+cmdline_hist    +fork()          +mouse_sgr       -sniff           +windows
+cmdline_info    +gettext         -mouse_sysmouse  +startuptime     +writebackup
+comments        -hangul_input    +mouse_urxvt     +statusline      +X11
+conceal         +iconv           +mouse_xterm     -sun_workshop    -xfontset
+cryptv          +insert_expand   +multi_byte      +syntax          +xim
+cscope          +jumplist        +multi_lang      +tag_binary      +xsmp_interact
+cursorbind      +keymap          -mzscheme        +tag_old_static  +xterm_clipboard
+cursorshape     +langmap         +netbeans_intg   -tag_any_white   -xterm_save
+dialog_con_gui  +libcall         +path_extra      -tcl             +xpm
+diff            +linebreak       +perl/dyn        +terminfo        
+digraphs        +lispindent      +persistent_undo +termresponse    
+dnd             +listcmds        +postscript      +textobjects     
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-7.4.729-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/vim-7.4.729-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-7.4.729-2.x86_64/src/vim74=/usr/src/debug/vim-7.4.729-2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -fstack-protector  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lz -lGL -lpixman-1 -lEGL -lm -lpthread -lGL -lm -lpthread -lXdamage -lXfixes -lX11-xcb -lxcb-glx -lxcb-shm -lxcb-render -lXrender -lXext -lX11 -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpng16 -lm -lz -lgio-2.0 -lz -lpangoft2-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lpango-1.0 -lm -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lffi -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpcre -lfontconfig -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lz -lpng16 -lm -lz -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lz -lpng16 -lm -lz  -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lelf    -lncursesw -liconv -lintl   -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE -lperl -ldl -lcrypt
```

Answer (score 4):

Vim is using Unicode (probably UTF-8), but Excel and/or Access are using [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (or possibly a related Windows code page such as 1251 or 1253). Decimal 8216 is hexadecimal 2018, thus `‘` is Unicode character U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

[`Asc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/asc-function) and [`Chr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function) are old, pre-Unicode functions, which is why they are reporting the Windows-1252 character codes. If you use `AscW` and `ChrW` instead, you will find that Access and Excel use the same values as Vim.

`:set encoding=cp1252` will tell Vim to use the Windows-1252 character encoding. Any non-ASCII characters, such as smart quotes, that already in your buffer will displayed as multiple characters ([mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)), but any new smart single quotes you enter will use 145 and 146. If you’re not sure how to type them in Vim, enter Insert mode and press `Ctrl-K ' 6` for `‘` and `Ctrl-K ' 9` for `’`. `ga` will now show that `‘` is decimal 145 and `’` is 146. `:set coding=utf-8` will return Vim to UTF-8 encoding.

In general, I would suggest using `AscW` and `ChrW` instead of `Asc` and `Chr`, and I would not suggest switching Vim’s encoding to Windows-1252.

Comment: Thanks, Lithis.  Lot to chew on there.  I will try to gnaw on it this weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file encoding-names include cp1251 and cp1253, but not cp1252. Maybe because my gvim was compiled for Cygwin, years ago. The digraphs entered with ctrl-k replicate the odd characters in vim, but I find that I have to use chr() instead of string literals because they occur in a text SQL file that gets read by specific VBA fuction, and the literal characters aren't properly read.  In the face this, the only reason I need the literal character is to find out the code so that I can refer to it using chr(). My current solution is asc() in the VBA editor's Immediate window.

Comment: Vim’s encoding `latin1` is actually the same as `cp1252`, as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372767/4896941 .

Comment: Thanks. If I `set encoding=latin1`, I can't properly paste the odd tick mark into the buffer from register * (the Windows buffer).  It shows up as an upside-down question mark with decimal code 191.  Setting back to utf-8 allows me to paste the odd tick mark, decimal code 8217.